# I'd like it vs. I'd like that?

Tags: articles

I'm a native English speaker, and I'm trying to explain to my Russian friend what the difference is but I just can't.

I asked her if she would like for me to send her some songs that could help improve her English (she already has a very advanced level) and she said "I'd like it!". I know that in this situation, "I'd like it!" doesn't sound too bad, but it sounds a bit more unnatural to me than "I'd like that" would.

Any explanations?

Comment: It’s the difference between “I’d like it *if you would do that*.” And “I’d like that. (What you just said)”

Comment: I think the difference is mainly to do with the immediacy and the personal nature of the offer. If you said to someone "What would you think if I came to help with the garden next week?" they would say "I'd like that" but if you said "How would it be if I gave you a hug right now?" they'd be more likely to say "I'd like it". Having said that there's a huge overlap where either one is just as likely as the other.